# Top 3 values of JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I only send the top 3 values of my JSON file?

**xp.json**

```
{
  "405778045941841923":{"xp":12601,"level":43},
  "437502925019807744":{"xp":221,"level":1},
  "258877808489660416":{"xp":6623,"level":23}, ...
}
```

**index.js**

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}list`) {
    console.log(Object.keys(xpfile).reduce((list, username) => {
        list += `${username}: XP: ${xp[username].xp}\n`
        return list
    }, ''))
}
```

**output:**

```
405778045941841923: XP: 12601
437502925019807744: XP: 221
258877808489660416: XP: 6623
381904022132752384: XP: 81
170563606109356032: XP: 2116
375336450008416267: XP: 70
400012805018746891: XP: 3494
400731769927761941: XP: 9152
327157513105571840: XP: 11 ...
```

I would appreciate any code example since I am having a hard time calling JSON objects in code, I basically only want to show the top 3 highest XP

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd sort, slice and reduce

```js
let j = {"405778045941841923":{"xp":12601,"level":43},"437502925019807744":{"xp":221,"level":1},"258877808489660416":{"xp":6623,"level":23}};
let top3 = Object.keys(j).sort((a, b) => j[b].xp - j[a].xp).slice(0, 3).reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b] = j[b];
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(top3);
```

If you only want the xp without the rest of the objects, you could use the following

```
let top3 = Object.values(j).map(({xp}) => xp).sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0, 3);
console.log(top3);
```

Comment: How could I send the output to a chat because it shows that top3 is empty, in the console it has proper output

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
  "405778045941841923":{"xp":12601,"level":43},
  "437502925019807744":{"xp":221,"level":1},
  "258877808489660416":{"xp":6623,"level":23},
  "777877805559660416":{"xp":6623,"level":25},
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key, index) {
  if(index <= 2){
    console.log(`${key}: XP: ${data[key].xp}`);
  }else{
      
    return;
  }
});
```

Using a `Map` function or `forEach` to loop thru the element and custom the output as you wish

Answer (score 0):

```js
let xpObj= {"405778045941841923":{"xp":12601,"level":43},"437502925019807744":{"xp":221,"level":1},"258877808489660416":{"xp":6623,"level":23}}
let sortedArray = Object.values(xpObj).map((xpVal) => xpVal.xp).sort((first,second)=>second-first);

console.log("top three are",sortedArray[0],sortedArray[1],sortedArray[2])
```